# How much router packet loss is acceptable?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, isp

I have had issues with my internet connection. My ISP has several times dropped my internet connection all together and it has been down for several days. When calling support they analyse and call city fiber owner and then they come back telling me it works fine. But I never get any explanation of the root cause. They often say it might be my bad and caused by household inner problems.

I am tired of it and decided to upgrade. I bought two "Netgear ProSafe Plus GS116Ev2" switches and two "ASUS ZenWiFi AX (XT8) AV6600". Most of the time it works pretty fine, but sometimes I drop signal during video calls or movie watching. Last week the connection went down completely and was gone for 5 days. Then suddenly it all works again. This is not acceptable as I now work from home full time. Support was of no help.

I have been an IT professional developer for 30 years but I am not very skilled in networks. I downloaded PingPlotter and started to monitor. I typically get good results from all hops in the trace route, EXCEPT for local router and ISP "central router"(?) that show very high packet loss of 60-90%.

Is that a problem? What should be my next step?

Typical plotter result:

[image: typical plotter result]

Comment: I get solid performance from my ISP Hitron modem. The first router in is a Cisco VPN router.  I do not get observable packet loss in normal use over months and months of use.

Comment: For best 'net in Sweden (well known ISP visible in the image), swap to Bahnhof. I've just ended a three year subscription period where I don't *remember* having had any trouble. Any packet loss beyond a percent or two is "too much" IMO.

Comment: Hmm... Note though: A device may have ping responses turned off.

Comment: I suggest using Smokeping and known-good ping targets (Google DNS, Cloudflare DNS, possibly others) to measure packet loss.

Answer (score 1):

General packet loss should be less than 1%.

However, what your ping plot shows is not general packet loss, it's just a couple routers that don't bother responding to pings very often. Note that only those two routers have high rates of ping losses. If they were generally dropping all types of traffic at that high of a packet loss rate, all the hops after them would show the same or higher packet loss, as true packet loss is cumulative across the path.